# Cant display global Variable in Frontend .html

Tags: api, ionic-framework, maps

have some Problems with my Variables and dont understand why. Iam trying to access a global Variable, but cant display its Value?

Is it because of the asynchronous Thread?

```py
public cityName: string = "";


if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
        this.nativeGeocoder.reverseGeocode(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude, this.nativeoptions)
        .then((result: NativeGeocoderResult[]) => console.log(result[0]))
        .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
      });
    } else {
      this.cityName = "";
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location) {
        let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude);
        googleMapsGeo.geocode({'location': latLng}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            if (results[0]) {
              this.cityName = results[0]['address_components'][2]['long_name'];
            } else {
              this.cityName = "";
              window.alert('No results found');
            }
          } else {
            this.cityName = "";
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
          }
        });
      });
    }
```

And home.page.html

```py
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
      <div class="ion-text-center">
        <ion-title
        *ngFor=""
        >{{cityName}}</ion-title>
      </div>  
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

PS: console.log() returns the right value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's a copy/paste error, but you have a `*ngFor=""` in your code that shouldn't be there:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
      <div class="ion-text-center">
        <ion-title
        *ngFor="" <---------------- here!
        >{{cityName}}</ion-title>
      </div>  
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Besides that I noticed in your code that you're using arrow functions at first, but then you use

```
// ...

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location) { 
  // ...

  this.cityName = ...;
})
```

Doing `function(location) {...}` overrides what `this` means, so `this.cityName` doesn't refer to your component property anymore. In order to avoid that, you would need to use *arrow functions*, doing something like `(location) => { ... }` instead. I'll recommend reading **[the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)** to understand how arrow functions work.

So using arrow functions, your code would look like this:

```
if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {

  this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
    this.nativeGeocoder.reverseGeocode(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude, this.nativeoptions)
      .then((result: NativeGeocoderResult[]) => console.log(result[0]))
      .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
  });

} else {

  this.cityName = "";

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((location) => { // <---- here!
    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude);

    googleMapsGeo.geocode({ 'location': latLng }, (results, status) => { // <---- and here!
      if (status === 'OK') {
        if (results[0]) {
          this.cityName = results[0]['address_components'][2]['long_name'];
        } else {
          this.cityName = "";
          window.alert('No results found');
        }
      } else {
        this.cityName = "";
        window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, was the arrow functions!

Comment: @Daniel glad to help :)